# Algorithm to calculate score/rating based on multiple performance based indicators

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, scoring

First of all, I have to confess that my math skills are not the best and I would appreciate if you could please keep your response as simple as possible (preferably in layman's term).

I'm trying to create a scoring system for some performance reporting that I'm currently working on. There's a lot of data to go through, so I thought that a way I can help with when navigating the data would be to create a system that scores our campaigns (some type of efficiency indicator) based on a couple of variables/indicators (listed below). This would allow us to promptly identify and prioritize low performing campaigns. I would appreciate if you could please help me create an algorithm that could solve for this issue.

**List Variables/Indicators:**

1. **Requests (This is an amount):** This represents the amount of times a campaign has the chance to serve an impression to a user. The highest this number the better it is.
2. **Ads (This is an amount):** This the amount of Requests that passed any targeting criteria. If not, then it would generate an Error (listed below) count. The highest this number the better it is.
3. **Opportunity (This is an amount):** This represents the amount of times a campaign is ready to serve an impression. The highest this number the better it is.
4. **Margin (This is an amount):** This represents the campaign's
   profitability.The highest this number the better it is.
5. **Error (This is an amount):** This represents the amount of time an error was generated, which prevented an impression from being displayed. The lowest this number the better it is.

Thanks in advance for the help and please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide to help.

Comment: One way would be to assign weights (negative for the errors) to these indicators and just sum the contributions to get a single value that you can use as an overall indicator (`w1 * requests + w2 * ads + ...`).

Comment: Hi  @NicoSchertler, thanks for getting back me. Is there any way to find the the correct weights? The issue I'm encountering is that I can't really guess how positively or negatively a variable could affect the whole score.

Comment: There is no right or wrong here. Assigning these weights is a task for a domain expert (not for a programmer). If you can't assign these weights, you might be able to extract them from some example orderings. But this requires a lot of samples and quite some statistical background.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, got it. Thanks for all the help.